# QUERY no filtra resultado correctamente

Tags: mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Tengo el siguiente query :

```
SELECT  pe.id_person , pa.id_person_patient , *  
FROM patient as pa INNER JOIN person as pe  on ( pa.id_person_patient = pe.id_person ) 
WHERE pe.elimination_date is null OR pe.elimination_date = 0  
AND pe.name = 'ALEJANDRA' 
GROUP by pa.id_person_patient
```

Pero la clausula

```
AND pe.name = 'ALEJANDRA'
```

Me devuelve un resultado que no es valido. ¿Por qué me devuelva un row con el nombre `'TEST'`, si la clausula dice que solo busque nombre donde dice `'alejandra'`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedo apreciar el resultado completo de la query pero asumo que es por una falla en agrupación de condiciones en el `where` por lo que debería ser:

```
SELECT  pe.id_person , pa.id_person_patient , *  
FROM patient as pa INNER JOIN person as pe  on ( pa.id_person_patient = pe.id_person ) 
WHERE (pe.elimination_date is null OR pe.elimination_date = 0) 
AND pe.name = 'ALEJANDRA' 
GROUP by pa.id_person_patient
```

Esto para asegurar que las dos primeras se evaluarán primero y serán contrastadas con la última.

Comment: Efectivamente era por la agrupación de el OR..no tengo bien analizado por que, pero es lo que fallaba.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que a falta de agrupación el SGBD asumía esta agrupación: `pe.elimination_date is null OR (pe.elimination_date = 0 
AND pe.name = 'ALEJANDRA')` por lo que sólo era necesario que `pe.elimination_date` sea nulo.